# Transferring a jar file to a remote EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, jar

I'm using Apache Spark in AWS EC2 server. When I submit a job to the Spark, I made my code as jar files.

Since my code is rarely modified, I do 'git clone' my code from Github and create jar files when the EC2 server is created.

However, I heard that it is not good to clone the code directly in the server and I can't find 'why' in the Google. So my question is, when transferring a jar file to a remote EC2 server, which one below is best?

1. The way I do now.
2. Creating a jar file on local dev server, upload it to AWS s3, and use it(I saw this the way most often when I googled about it).
3. Creating a jar file locally and transfer it to the remote server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me 2nd Option is best among the 3. Only a slight modification to it. You can push the jar to s3 from your build pipeline instead of uploading the jar from local. This way you have control of jar upload also. And you can use IAM role for this. Also, you can use IAM role to pull the jar from S3.

In the first option, you need to store GitHub username and password in EC2 instance also you need to open the port for the same. Which is not recommended.

In the third option, you need to keep the port open in the Ec2 instance which is again not recommended. Also for scp you need to share the cluster username and password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By the way could you explain me why 2nd option is the best? @dassum

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Thanks!